# accessing the values from a Tensor Variable of Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I have modified the sample code of autoencoder to suit my data. I want to know a way in which i can access the layer_1 values of the encoder. 
I want to use the encoder encoded values as the features for the input data and do further analysis on that.
The input is of 200 dimensions and the encoder has 100 hidden nodes.

```
from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import word2vec

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.01
training_epochs = 200

#layer_1 = None
#layer_2 = None

# Network Parameters
n_hidden_1 = 100 # 1st layer num features
n_input = 200 # concatenation of 2 word vectors

X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input])

weights = {
    'encoder_h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1])),
    'decoder_h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_input])),
}
biases = {
    'encoder_b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'decoder_b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input])),
}

# Building the encoder
def encoder(x):
    #global layer_1
    layer_1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['encoder_h1']),
                               biases['encoder_b1']))
    return layer_1

# Building the decoder
def decoder(x):
    #global layer_2
    layer_2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['decoder_h1']),
                               biases['decoder_b1']))
    return layer_2


 # Construct model
encoder_op = encoder(X)
decoder_op = decoder(encoder_op)

# Prediction
y_pred = decoder_op
# Targets (Labels) are the input data.
y_true = X


# Define loss and optimizer, minimize the squared error
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.pow(y_true - y_pred, 2))
optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)    
    model = word2vec.load('./vectors.bin')    
    vector1 = (list(model['word1']))
    vector2 = (list(model['word2']))    
    input = []
    input.append(vector1+vector2)
    input_np = np.array(input)  
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={X: input_np}) 

    print(sess.run(w))
```

Comment: `sess.run(encoder_op)` ?

Comment: @martianwars 
    `sess.run(encoder_op)` .. I get an error 
You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float
[[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
[[Node: Sigmoid/_217 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_13_Sigmoid", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Comment: So run this line after the epoch loop?

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: Can you share your latest code?

Comment: I have posted the completed code. @martianwars

Answer (score 0):

In order to peer into what's going on in your TensorFlow computation, I recommend using [TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/summaries_and_tensorboard). TensorBoard includes [Summary Operations](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/summary) that can then be plotted in the UI to visualize the values of Tensors as the model trains.

For a high-level introduction, I highly recommend this YouTube video from the TensorFlow Dev Summit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBbEDRsCmv4